# Best way to quantify the tidal stress on an exoplanet?

Tags: exoplanet, tidal-forces

I'm trying to assess the tidal stresses different exoplanets experience during their orbits. The known parameters are usually mass $M$, radius $R$, eccentricity $e$, orbital period $T$, and semi-major axis $a$ (where the mass and radius of the host star are known as well).
The most straightforward way I can think of is using the tidal force imposed on the surface of the planet by the star:

$$ F_{tidal}= -2G\frac{M_*M_p}{\bar{r}^3}R_p$$

Where subscripts $*$ and $p$ represent the star and planet respectively.
$\bar{r}$ is the mean distance:

$$ \bar{r} = a \left( 1+ \frac{e^2}{2} \right)$$

and then dividing it by the surface area of the planet:

$$ \tau_{tidal}= \frac{F_{tidal}}{4\pi r_p^2}$$

However, I'm not sure if there is a better (and more appropriate) way to estimate the tidal stress.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem, along with some applications, is provided in the paper ``[The Ability of Significant Tidal Stress to Initiate Plate Tectonics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09898)'' by Zanazzi & Triaud.

More applications can be found in [the work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.03501) by McIntyre.